# How to calculate the ocurrence of a particular node in a XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML

```
<Root>
<PW>
  <Wec>
    <ID>11425</ID>
    <Data>
      <item>A3400301040TT01</item>
      <item>A3400301040TT02</item>
      <item>A3400301040TT03</item>
    </Data>
  </Wec>
  <Wec>
    <Data>
    <ID>11426</ID>
      <item>A3400302040TT01</item>
      <item>A3400302040TT03</item>
      <item>A3400302040TT02</item>
    </Data>
  </Wec>
</PW>
<PWSlots>
  <Rec>11</Rec>
  <Rec>12</Rec>
  <Rec>13</Rec>
  <Rec>14</Rec>
  <Rec>16</Rec>
  <Rec>15</Rec>
</PWSlots>
</Root>
```

And I want to generate an xml like this

```
<Root>
<PW>
  <Wec>
    <ID>11425</ID>
    <Data>
      <Item id="A3400301040TT01" slotNumber="11"/>
      <item id="A3400301040TT02" slotNumber="12"/>
      <item id="A3400301040TT03" slotNumber="13"/>
    </Data>
  </Wec>
  <Wec>
    <ID>11426</ID>
    <Data>        
      <item id="A3400302040TT01" slotNumber="14"/>
      <item id="A3400302040TT03" slotNumber="16"/>
      <item id="A3400302040TT02" slotNumber="15"/>
    </Data>
  </Wec>
</PW>
</Root>
```

Alright, so i am doing an xsl:foreach for every Wec tag and inside that foreach I have another one to loop through each item tag.
The problem comes when I try to include the slot as part of the item since I am looping inside an specific Wec Node.

I need a mechanism that based on a particular item tag I can get the current ocurrence of that item node (in the whole xml string) to know the specific Rec tag I have to assign from the PWSlots.

To give an example, I am looping in the first Wec tag (ID 11425). Since this is the first ocurrence of the node item I have to assign the value of the first Rec tag under PWSlots.

Any idea on how to do this using XSL??
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is use a push approach instead of a pull and use `xsl:number` and `position()` to get the correct `Rec` value.

I didn't change the location of `ID` in the second `Wec` because it seems like a typo. If this needs to move and you can't figure it out, let me know.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<Root>
    <PW>
        <Wec>
            <ID>11425</ID>
            <Data>
                <item>A3400301040TT01</item>
                <item>A3400301040TT02</item>
                <item>A3400301040TT03</item>
            </Data>
        </Wec>
        <Wec>
            <Data>
                <ID>11426</ID>
                <item>A3400302040TT01</item>
                <item>A3400302040TT03</item>
                <item>A3400302040TT02</item>
            </Data>
        </Wec>
    </PW>
    <PWSlots>
        <Rec>11</Rec>
        <Rec>12</Rec>
        <Rec>13</Rec>
        <Rec>14</Rec>
        <Rec>16</Rec>
        <Rec>15</Rec>
    </PWSlots>
</Root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:variable name="pos">
            <xsl:number level="any"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <item id="{.}" slotNumber="{/*/PWSlots/Rec[number($pos)]}"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PWSlots"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Root>
   <PW>
      <Wec>
         <ID>11425</ID>
         <Data>
            <item id="A3400301040TT01" slotNumber="11"/>
            <item id="A3400301040TT02" slotNumber="12"/>
            <item id="A3400301040TT03" slotNumber="13"/>
         </Data>
      </Wec>
      <Wec>
         <Data>
            <ID>11426</ID>
            <item id="A3400302040TT01" slotNumber="14"/>
            <item id="A3400302040TT03" slotNumber="16"/>
            <item id="A3400302040TT02" slotNumber="15"/>
         </Data>
      </Wec>
   </PW>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 2):

I like @Daniel's approach better. But here is an alternative solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- remove PWSlots -->
   <xsl:template match="PWSlots" />

   <xsl:template match="item">
      <xsl:variable name="id" select="normalize-space()" />
      <xsl:variable name="pos">
         <xsl:for-each select="//item">
            <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.)=$id">
               <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <Item id="{.}">
         <xsl:attribute name="slotNumber">
            <xsl:value-of select="//PWSlots/Rec[number($pos)]" />
         </xsl:attribute>
      </Item>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I like `number($pos)` more than `position()=$pos`. I've used that a lot in the past; not sure why I forgot it this time. I'm going to update my answer :-) +1

Comment: @DanielHaley: Why not just `[$pos]`, since you know that `$pos` will be a number (if it will work at all)?

Comment: @LarsH - That's what I first tried, but it didn't work for me. Since this is XSLT 1.0, it just returned the first occurrence (`11`). If this was 2.0, I would use `as="xs:integer"` on the `xsl:variable` and then I could use just `[$pos]`.

Comment: @DanielHaley: ok, I think I get it. `$pos` may be an RTF that can be converted to a number, but since it's not a number, it just gets evaluated as an RTF-as-boolean when in `[$pos]`.